# How do I add an animation in my $modalService with angular-strap?

Tags: angularjs, angular-strap

I am creating a modal with `angular-strap`

When I create a modal in my markup, the animation works like expected. Here is an example:

```
<a href="" bs-modal="settings.deleteAccountModal" data-animation="am-fade-and-slide-top" data-template="js/donor/settings/confirm-modal.html" class="trashOut"></a>
```

But when I try to create the same modal with the $modalService, the animation does not work. Here is my js code:

```
this.openModal = function() {
        $modal({
            animation: 'am-fade-and-slide-top',
            backdropAnimation: 'am-fade',
            scope: $scope,
            title: "Are you sure?",
            backdrop: 'static',
            template: 'js/donor/settings/confirm-modal.html',
            show: true
        });
    };
```

How do I configure the animations with the $modalService?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown in https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-strap/issues/1101
, you need to add

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="//rawgithub.com/mgcrea/angular-motion/master/dist/angular-motion.min.css">`

on your page and inject ngAnimate at the same time. See the [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/uK4QxyWnlvBWzsZ7MnPW?p=preview) written by [vmlf01](https://github.com/vmlf01). This is his answer, and thank him very much.

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", ['mgcrea.ngStrap', 'ngAnimate']);
```